# Why keep a private key in uPort?

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, private-key, public-key, uport

Reading the uport whitepaper https://uport.me/library/pdf/whitepaper.pdf :

The purpose of having a Proxy contract as the core identifier is defined as :

> The purpose of having a Proxy contract as the core identifier is that
>   it allows the user to replace their private key while maintaining a
>   persistent identifier. If the user’s uPort identifier instead was the
>   public key corresponding to their private key, they would lose control
>   over their identifier if they were to lose the device where the
>   private key is held.

Why do I need my private key ? If the proxy contract is essentially acting as a private key in that it's used to identify me then why keep the private key ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You still need the private key to control your proxy contract, but it is replaceable, whereas you identity is persistent.

If you lose your private key, there's a way to configure another private key as the controller of your proxy contract (that way you don't lose your identity, that's the "hack").